# Ordered insertion in linked list is not adding the node

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm new to Python. I was trying to code an ordered insertion into a linked list -- so that the list remains ordered in ascending order.

However, the list remains empty after I call `my_linked_list.as_order(1)`

What am I doing wrong?

```
def as_order(self,x):
    new_node=Node(x)
    if self.head is None or self.head.data < x:
        n=self.head
        new_node.next=n
        n=new_node
    else:
        n=self.head
        while(n.next is not None and n.next.data < x):
            n=n.next
        new_node.next=n.next
        n.next=new_node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- It never assigns a value to `self.head`, so there is no way it can add a node to an empty list, or otherwise add a node that needs to become the first one in the list.
- Once the previous issue is solved, values that are greater than the head's value will be inserted *before* it, which violates the intended order.

Both errors are located in the same `if` block. So change this:

```
if self.head is None or self.head.data < x:
    n=self.head
    new_node.next=n
    n=new_node
```

to this:

```
if self.head is None or self.head.data >= x:  # corrected comparison
    new_node.next = self.head  # (simplification)
    self.head = new_node  # make new node the head
```